# Как сделать вывод многих изображений на JS?

Tags: javascript, jquery

К примеру есть сайт TEST.RU, на котором хранятся изображения под именем 1,2,3,4,5.....и т.д. То есть: TEST.RU/IMG/1.JPG Как вывести эти изображения, но при условии, что к примеру изображения5 нету.... то есть циклом они должны еще и проверятся на наличие изображния, на PHP я использую: getimagesize.... Но на PHP это очень долго....
JS только изучаю, помогите пожалуйста кодом...

Answer (score 0):

Первое что пришло в голову,проверять Аяксом через HEAD... проверяет с 0 элемента, постоянно добавляя объекты на страницу. Можно конечно собрать значения с номером i в массив и потом пройтись по этому массиву и одним махом добавить то количество элементов которое есть. Но опять таки, определить как-то сколько файлов есть на фтп с подобным названием - малореально в таких реалиях. Мой вариант таков, хоть и действие сиё бесконечное.

```js
var i = 0;
setInterval(function(){
   console.log(i);
   var imgUrl = 'www.TEST.RU/IMG/'+i+'.JPG';
      $.ajax({
        url: imgUrl,
        type:'HEAD',
        error: function() { // if image not set.
         console.log('картинки с'+imgUrl+' нет');
         i++
         },
         success: function() { // if image is set.
            $('body').append(`<img src="${imgUrl}">`);
            i++;
         }
      });
   },100)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```